# Maximal analytic extension of Robinson-Bertotti geometry

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, reissner-nordstrom-metric

I want to find a maximal analytic extension of the Robinson-Bertotti metric given by
$$ds^2 = - \lambda^2 dt^2 +Q^2 \frac{d\lambda^2}{\lambda^2}+Q^2d\Omega_{S^2}^2.$$
Where $Q$ is a constant charge and $d\Omega_{S^2}^2$ is the line element of the $2$-sphere. Here is what I did so far. I state the coordinate transformations and try to keep track of the ranges of the coordinates.

**1. Coordinate transformation**
$$u=t+\frac{Q}{\lambda} ~~~\Rightarrow u \in (-\infty,\infty]$$
$$v=t-\frac{Q}{\lambda} ~~~\Rightarrow v \in [-\infty,\infty)$$
This transforms the line element to
$$ds^2=-\Big(\frac{2Q}{u-v}\Big)^2 du dv+Q^2 d\Omega_{S^2}^2.$$
 **2. Coordinate transformation**
$$u=\tan\Big(\frac{U}{2}\Big)~~~\Rightarrow U \in (-\pi,\pi]$$
$$v=-\cot\Big(\frac{V}{2}\Big)~~~\Rightarrow V \in (-\pi,\pi)$$
This transforms the line element to
$$ds^2=-\frac{Q^2}{\cos\big(\frac{U-V}{2}\big)}dUdV + Q^2 d\Omega_{S^2}^2.$$
**3. Coordinate transformation**
$$T=\frac{1}{2}\Big(U+V\Big) ~~~\Rightarrow u \in (-\pi,\pi)$$
$$R=\frac{1}{2}\Big(U-V\Big) ~~~\Rightarrow u \in (-\pi,\pi)$$
This transforms the line element to
$$ds^2=\Phi^2 \Big[-dT^2+dR^2+\cos^2(R) d\Omega_{S^2}^2\Big].$$ With the overall conformal factor $\Phi^2 = \Big(\frac{Q}{\cos(R)}\Big)^2.$

Now to my questions:

- Regarding the first transformation: Is it correct to include $\infty$ and $-\infty$ in the ranges of $u$ and $v$ respectively? I think so because of the singularity at $\lambda=0$ but I can't justify it mathematically.
- Regarding the second transformation: Do I have to take something into account because of the discontinuity of $\arctan(-\frac{1}{v})$ at $v=0$. Also I think I should be done here regarding finding the maximal analytic extension but I want to deduce the Carter Penrose diagram, that's why I did another transformation.
- Is it correct that the Carter-Penrose diagram of this metric looks exactly the same as that from the Minkowski spacetime? If not why? It seems strange to me because this spacetime is the near horizon limit of the extremal Reissner-Nordström black hole, where I wouldn't expect the same causal structure as in flat space.

Comment: You might want to recheck your first coordinate transformation.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I found a mistake in my calculations - I somehow changed the $Q^2$ to a $\lambda^2$ in front of the $2$-sphere line element during the calculation. Did you mean that?

Comment: Hi, I know this question is from two months ago but I'm just doing it now and was wondering if you ever got an answer from elsewhere as to why the metric is like Minkowski even though it's the RN near the boundary? The metric is AdS x S^2 (and the penrose diagram only plots AdS), and there's only 3 maximally symmetric flat spacetimes (Minkowski, AdS, and dS) so I'm not too surprised the diagram is like Minkowski but I'm still surprised we get a flat metric

Comment: Although, I guess the metric can have flat hypersurfaces without it necessarily being flat everywhere (like  Painleve-Gullstrand coordinates for Shwarzschild)